# Navigation bar not showing in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, xib

I'm new to iOS development and am having trouble getting the nav bar to show. I've been searching through all the answers to when this question has been asked previously and can't find where my issues is. I'm using a navigation controller. Can any of you see what's wrong with my settings? Much appreciated.
[Nav bar settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDYKN.png)
[Emulator screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v49RN.png)

Sorry for the lack of pictures. Looks like I'm limited to two.

Answer (score 3):

Select Navigation Controller in the Attributes Inspector check "is Initial View Controller".

Comment: Wow, thank you. Should've tried that. I thought the first view controller was supposed to be the initial view controller. Thank you very much!